# Bash - How to strip the first and last slash in a string if present?

Tags: bash

What is the most effective way to get:

```
'a/b/c'
```

out of input string that can be any of the following:

```
'/a/b/c/'
'a/b/c/'
'/a/b/c'
'a/b/c'
```

in a bash script?

Comment: I'd suggest a case construct, it should be pretty simple for those three cases (plus one default). Other than that, things like `sed` exist.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, I'm not familiar with bash language, I read in another question that sed is slow, will use it if no better choice

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't know about "most effective", but if that string is stored in the variable `a` (that is `$a` expands to the string) you can do:

```
b=${a#/} # Remove possible leading /
c=${b%/} # Remove possible trailing /
```

to put the desired string in the variable `c`.  This doesn't work if your input string contains single quotes as you have written in the question, but I suspect you did not intend to indicate that such quotes are in the string.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`, you can do:

```
echo "a/b/c/" | sed "s#^/\(.*\)#\1#" | sed "s#\(.*\)/\$#\1#"
```

Examples:

```
$ echo "/a/b/c/" | sed "s#^/\(.*\)#\1#" | sed "s#\(.*\)/\$#\1#"
a/b/c
$ echo "a/b/c/" | sed "s#^/\(.*\)#\1#" | sed "s#\(.*\)/\$#\1#"
a/b/c
$ echo "/a/b/c" | sed "s#^/\(.*\)#\1#" | sed "s#\(.*\)/\$#\1#"
a/b/c
$ echo "a/b/c" | sed "s#^/\(.*\)#\1#" | sed "s#\(.*\)/\$#\1#"
a/b/c
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo "/a/b/c" | sed 's/^\///;s/\/$//'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a trick, but it's only going to output a/b/c, as long as its present in the input.

```
echo '/a/b/c/' | grep --only-matching 'a/b/c'
```